# Como detectar si un dato ingresado es una letra en psint

Tags: switch

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa de psint, pero llegue al momento de meter datos, si se ingresa una letra el programa se cae, quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de detectar si ingreso una letra en la siguiente comprobación.

[image: imagen del diagrama]

```
Algoritmo rentaDeVehiculos
OP <- 0
Escribir 'Autos UP Bienbenido'
Repetir
    Escribir 'Seleccione un vehiculo'
    Escribir '1 = Ferrari'
    Escribir '2 = Bochito'
    Escribir '3 = Motocicleta'
    Leer lista_de_variables
    Mientras lista_de_variables == strcmp Hacer
        Escribir "Agrego una leta"
    FinMientras
    Segun lista_de_variables  Hacer
        1:
            Escribir 'Ferrari $1500'
            Escribir '¿Cuantos dias va a rentar?'
            Leer diasFe
            Mientras diasFe<=1 Hacer
                Escribir 'Datos incorrectos intentelo de nuevo'
                Leer diasFe
            FinMientras
            ferrari <- 1500
            total <- diasFe*ferrari
            Escribir 'El total a pagar es: $',total
            OP <- 1
```